# Is this authentication scheme using JWT secure?

Tags: authentication, session-management, token, jwt

I was wondering if you could review this authentication scheme for web application.

*=== Login Page ===*
Credentials Verification => Server issues JWT => Stored in a Cookie

**JWT contains:**
exp: timestamp
uid: UserID
HMAC-SHA512 Signature

**Redis stores:**
Key: UserID
Value: SecretKey (Only inserted if does not exist)

*=== Authentication of Requests ===*
**JWT Decoded**
$uid = UserID

**Redis gets:**
Value: SecretKey from
Key: $uid

**JWT HMAC Verification using SecretKey**
if verified
if exp not expired

**ALL OK**

So why using JWT at all when this is actually a stateful scheme and not stateless?

- Verification performs only a single query to Redis, there is no need to do another to get the UserID
- No need to store SessionID for every session, Redis stores only one record for unlimited sessions of given user.
- No need to maintain expired sessions in Redis and delete them.
- All tokens of a single user can be revoked anytime by changing SecretKey

Please tell me whether it is stupid or there are any security flaws so I do not implement crap.

Answer (score 0):

In general looks good. However, few issues to think of

- The userID isn't encrypted. If the request is not going over TLS, it's leaking that info to MITM. You might want to encrypt it.
- Once user logs out, what prevents the JWT from still getting used, assuming it's not expired?

Comment: Hello Sunil, thanks for the review. I'm using TLSv1.2 only. That's good point, nothing prevents JWT from getting used, maybe I could use Bloom Filter for 'logged out' tokens?

Comment: Bloom filter is definitely worth looking into. How do you plan to GC on expiry?

Comment: GC could be executed on every x write to the bloom.